# How do I subscribe for changes from Shared Database?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

When I create subscription:

```
let options: CKSubscriptionOptions = [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordUpdate, .firesOnRecordDeletion]
let subscription = CKDatabaseSubscription(recordType: "Territory", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
```

and save it to my shared database:

```
sharedDatabase?.save(subscription) { _, _ in }
```

It still doesn't appear in my Cloudkit dashboard. Why?

[image]

While for private database, appears...

[image]

After I register I need to know what record has changed and what type of change it was.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a *custom zone* where to save your `Territory` record type using `CKDatabaseSubscription`

> Be aware that CKQuerySubscription is not supported in the shared
>   database, and CKDatabaseSubscription currently only tracks the changes
>   from custom zones in the private and shared database.

More info at [Technical Q&A QA1917](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1917/_index.html)

Comment: yes, it works... but the case is when I get notification about change in shared db then I also get CKDatabaseNotification and I cannot access CKRecors this notification is related with

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you ever figured this out, it's been a year, but:

```
func subscribeToSharedDBForRecordType(recordType:String){

        let newSubscription = CKDatabaseSubscription()
        newSubscription.recordType = recordType

        let info = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
        info.soundName = "default"
        info.alertBody = "Something changed the record!"
        newSubscription.notificationInfo = info

        CKContainer.default().sharedCloudDatabase.save(newSubscription) { [weak self] savedSubscription, error in

            guard let savedSubscription = savedSubscription, error == nil else {
                print("error saving subscription:\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            UserDefaults.standard.set(newSubscription.subscriptionID, forKey: "someUniqueKey")
        }

    }
```

Will subscribe you to all changes to the given record type in the shared db. The next thing to do would be to look at the zone notification to determine which zone was affected. I didn't do that for my project, so I don't know how.